# Каркас многопоточного приложения Win32 на C++

Tags: winapi, многопоточность, c++

Пытаюсь спроектировать каркас для приложения, думаю пока так:

Создан первичный поток T1, используем его для основной логики управления приложением (своего рода ядро приложения). После инициализации всех дополнительных потоков (модули приложения) переходим к циклу обработки сообщений, в котором обрабатываем сообщения посланные другими потоками (модулями) и согласно заложенной логике либо обрабатываем либо пересылаем в другой поток.

Поток T2 создаёт главное окно приложения со всеми его компонентами, запускает свой цикл обработки сообщений, обеспечивает логику работы окна и компонентов, в случае необходимости посылает сообщения в поток T1 (ядро приложения).

Поток T3 работает по принципу Т2 и создаёт дочернее окно - форму с контролами и тп.

Поток Т4 своего окна не создаёт, является хранилищем данных или сервером или ещё чем угодно, не принципиально. Так же имеет свой цикл обработки сообщения.

То есть обмен данными идет через Windows сообщения, в случае если необходимо передать строку или массив, передаём в сообщении указатель на него. Естественно не забываем про синхронизацию данных.

А что думают бывалые программисты!? :)

Comment: - Если вы преследуете цель создать свой собственный framework и хотите сделать его **хорошо,** то посмотрите как аналогичные проблемы и вопросы [решаются в `Qt.`](http://qt.digia.com/Product/)

- Если же вы такой цели не преследуете, а решаете какую-то вполне конкретную задачу, то то, что вы описали — явный overkill. Вы на синхронизацию между потоками потратите времени больше, чем на все остальное вместе взятое.

- Попробуйте мыслить объектами, абстракциями, а не потоками и message loop'ами, поскольку они являются деталями реализации и к глобальной задаче обычно относятся крайне опосредованно

Comment: Пытаюсь мыслить и объектами, (вы имели в виду объекты классов?) получается что для каждого класса будет использован один объект (исходя из задачи описанной выше) будет ли оправдано использовать классы? Да и вопрос о взаимодействии объектов остаётся открытым (для меня)

Comment: К примеру как передавать данные между объектами? Пусть есть 3 класса - A(приложение, логика приложения), B(главное окно), C(интерфейс для связи с другим процессом)
class A {B objB; C objC;};
В объекте objB была нажата кнопка, это событие нужно передать в объект класса A как это лучше сделать? Мне кажется, что при инициализации objB ему передаётся this и при необходимости можно будет вызвать интерфейсную функцию класса A из objB, это правильный подход?

Comment: Тем временем, в objC через CallBack вызывается член функция, причём потоком другого процесса, в этот момент необходимо запустить таймер, по срабатыванию которого требуется вызвать функцию объекта класса A! Для работы таймера необходим loop, он в другом процессе или нет не знаю, то есть нет гарантии что из "чужого" потока его вообще можно запустить! Вот что здесь делать?